# Proof of Lagrangian equations

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation

Context: Trying to proof Lagrangian equations without an explicit usage of the concept of virtual displacement.

(disclaimer for happy close-vote triggers: I'm not related to any academic institution as student nor as teacher nor as dean)

Let a position vector in generalized coordinates $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{r}(q_0,\dots,q_n,t)$, velocity $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$, kinetic energy $T=\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\mathbf{r}}\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ and $V=V(q_0,\dots,q_n,t)$ a potential field.

With these definitions it is easy to find that:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_k}}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k} = m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k}$$

By Newton's second law and potential definition, $m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}=-\nabla V$. Replacing in previous:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_k}}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k} = m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = ( - \nabla V ) \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} $$

From this point, to proof Lagrangian equations it remains to verify that:

$$ ( - \nabla V ) \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_k}$$

A possible path could be (?):

$$ ( - \nabla V ) \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = - \sum_i \frac{\partial V}{\partial q_i} \nabla q_i \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k}$$

and proof that:

$$ \nabla q_i \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = \delta_{ik}$$

(being $\delta_{ik}$ the Kronecker delta, 1 if $i=k$, $0$ otherwise)

but I do not know how to do this final step. Any hint? Or better continue the proof using another path ?

**Example**:

In usual 3D space with Cartesian coordinates, let particle position restricted to $\mathbf{r}=(r_x,r_y,r_z)=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, h )$.

It is immediately that:

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial \theta} = \left(\frac{\partial r_x}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial r_y}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial \theta} \right) = ( -\sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0)$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial h} = \left( \frac{\partial r_x}{\partial h}, \frac{\partial r_y}{\partial h}, \frac{\partial r_z}{\partial h} \right) = ( 0, 0, 1)$$

But how to express:

$$\nabla \theta = ( \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} ) = ?? $$
$$\nabla h = ( \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial h}{\partial z} ) = ?? $$

Note $\theta$ is not defined over all 3D space (x,y,z), it is defined only for the unit x-y circle.

Comment: I'm trying to interpret what the gradient of generalized coordinates mean.. I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: @Buraian: me too. I've added an example, could be some answer clarifies the subject.

Comment: I think you should change your question from being stuck on the identity to what part about proving that identity you are stuck ( I think it is that the identity is difficult to interpret only) because SE people usually like such questions better

Comment: You seem to use $T$ for a Lagrangian but it is T-V in this case.

Comment: @my2cts: move to the right the partial derivatives in $q_k$ for T and V , you get T-V=L. Moreover, recall partial derivative in $\dot{q_k}$ of V is zero, you get T-V also in left part.

Comment: Please note that if your question gets closed as "homework-like", that does not mean we think it is actually homework from some educational institution. It means it takes the form of a homework problem. Understand that the community at Physics.SE has decided that they do not want to sit around and solve people's problems for them. So, regardless the source of the problem, if we are asked to essentially do that, we are likely to close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(sorry to answer my own question)

If potential is written as $V(\mathbf{r}(q_0,\cdots,q_n))$ then is direct to find that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial q_k}V(\mathbf{r}(q_0,\cdots,q_n)) = \nabla V \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k}$$

and from previous one:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial T}{\partial \dot{q_k}}-\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_k} = m\ddot{\mathbf{r}}\frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = ( - \nabla V ) \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q_k}$$

finishing the proof.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following computation, where a summation is to be understood whenever there is repeated indices:

$$ \nabla q_{i}=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial r_j}\mathbf{e}_j$$
$$\partial_{k}\mathbf{r}=\frac{\partial r_l}{\partial q_k}\mathbf{e}_l$$

$$\nabla q_{i}\cdot\partial_{k}\mathbf{r}=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial r_j}\frac{\partial r_l}{\partial q_k}\mathbf{e}_j\cdot\mathbf{e}_l=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial r_j}\frac{\partial r_l}{\partial q_k}\delta_{jl}=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial r_j}\frac{\partial r_j}{\partial q_k}=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial q_k}=\delta_{ik}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. $\mathbf{r}$ is not used with two different meanings ? (particle position and full space). I've added an example to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is mixing of notation which may make it less obvious but in essence:

$$\nabla q_i \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = \frac{\partial q_i}{\partial\mathbf{r}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = \frac{\partial q_i}{\partial q_k} = \begin{cases}
0 \quad i\neq k\\
1 \quad i=k \\
\end{cases} =\delta_{ik}$$

Comment: could you detail $\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial\mathbf{r}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_k} = \frac{\partial q_i}{\partial q_k}$ ?.

Comment: Mathematicians may get angry if they see you doing that.. but (from the formal point of view) you can just "simplify" the $\mathbf{r}$.. it is just the chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: @Quillo: Means $\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial\mathbf{r}}$ directional derivative? Because applied to a scalar as $q_i$, directional derivative results in a scalar. Instead, $\nabla q_i$ results in a vector.

Comment: No, it is not the directional derivative. It is the gradient of $q_i$. This is exactly the point of @nluigi : $\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial\mathbf{r}} $ is just another way to write $\nabla q_i$